# LWJGL: glfwCreateWindow return null

Tags: java, lwjgl

I was trying LWJGL library in Java seeing the tutorial, but the creation of the window I will return null.

This is the code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;

public class Main implements Runnable {
    private int height = 720, width = height / 9 * 16;
    private String title = "Game";

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private long window;

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, title);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void init() {
        if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            System.err.println("Non riesco ad inizializzare GLFW!");
            return;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);

        if(window == NULL) {
            System.err.println("Non riesco a creare una finestra GLFW!");
            return;
        }

        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - width) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - height) / 2);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
        while(running) {
            update();
            render();

            if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE)
                running = false;
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    private void render() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }
}
```

Returns the following error:

```
Non riesco a creare una finestra GLFW!
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.lwjgl.system.Checks.checkPointer(Checks.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(GLFW.java:2546)
    at com.michele.flappybird.Main.render(Main.java:66)
    at com.michele.flappybird.Main.run(Main.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix? Thanks to anyone trying to help me.

Comment: Set an error callback to get debugging information: ``GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback = Callbacks.errorCallbackPrint(); glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);``

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be to simplify the program by removing the `Thread`, since LWJGL sometime has problems calling methods from outside the main thread. The second attempt would be to remove the `glfwWindowHint(...)` methods and instead call `glfwDefaultWindowHints()`

Comment: You probably mean `glfwDefaultWindowHints()`, although this isn't necessary here. But I think you are right about the thread: Most GLFW functions need to run on the main thread. See also [the documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro.html#thread_safety).